# mysql: hot reload on cert rotation

Tags: mysql, ssl-certificate

When using mysql, we can setup mysql to encrypt connectivity to / from the database using ssl certs.  But when the cert expires, we will have to renew it and upload another cert.  From the docs, it looks like the ssl cert variables are not dynamic, so is there any way to have mysql pick up the new certs once we've changed them on the file system (assuming we kept the name and location of the cert and key the same) without having to restart the mysql service?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I guess this is one where I should have read the manual.  Apparently, this capability was [added in mysql 8.0.16](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-encrypted-connections.html).

> As of MySQL 8.0.16, the **`tls_xxx`** and **`ssl_xxx`** system variables are
> dynamic and can be set at runtime, not just at startup. If changed
> with SET GLOBAL, the new values apply only until server restart. If
> changed with SET PERSIST, the new values also carry over to subsequent
> server restarts. See Section 13.7.6.1, “SET Syntax for Variable
> Assignment”. However, runtime changes to these variables do not
> immediately affect the TLS context for new connections, as explained
> later in this section.
>
> Along with the change in MySQL 8.0.16 that enables runtime changes to
> the TLS context-related system variables, the server enables runtime
> updates to the actual TLS context used for new connections. This
> capability may be useful, for example, to avoid restarting a MySQL
> server that has been running so long that its SSL certificate has
> expired.
>
> To create the initial TLS context, the server uses the values that the
> context-related system variables have at startup. To expose the
> context values, the server also initializes a set of corresponding
> status variables. The following table shows the system variables that
> define the TLS context and the corresponding status variables that
> expose the currently active context values.